# All irreducible factors of $p(x)=x^{p^n}-x \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ have degrees that divide $n$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

I want to prove that if I write $p(x)=x^{p^n}-x \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ as a product of irreducible polynomials, then the degree of each of them divides $n$.
I have already proved that any irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ whose degree is a divisor of $n$ divides $p(x)$. However I am stuck here. I have tried proving the main statement by reduction to absurd by assuming that
$$p(x)=q_1(x)\cdot \ldots \cdot q_s(x)$$
where, for example, $l = \deg(q_1(x))$ and $l$ doesn't divide $n$, but I haven't been able to reach a contradiction. Can someone help me?

Comment: All the ingredients are there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907353/irreducible-polynomial-in-mathbbf-px-divides-xpn-x  Again do you understand that $\Bbb{F}_p[t]/(q_j(t))$ is a field, with $p^{\deg (q_j)}$ elements ? And that the roots of $x^{p^n}-x$ form a field, with $p^n$ elements ?

Comment: @reuns yes I do but I don't know where does that lead me