# Every irreducible polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

My question is why does every irreducible polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $n$ split completely in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

I know that since $f$ has degree $n$, we have $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, and I also know that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the splitting field for the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x$, but I am having trouble connecting the dots.

Comment: From what you know, you can conclude that $f(x)$ is a divisor of $x^{p^n}-x$.

Comment: @metamorphy how?

Comment: $\gcd\big(f(x),x^{p^n}-x\big)$ (computed *over* $\mathbb{F}_p$!) is either $f$ or $1$, since $f$ is irreducible. But these polynomials have a common root in an extension, hence the latter possibility is ruled out.

Comment: Or consider the long division of $P$ by $q(x) = x^{p^n}-x$ as mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: @metamorphy How do we know these polynomials have a common root in an extension?

Comment: By *your* construction (essentially). A root of $f$ is an element of (a field isomorphic to) $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, hence a root of $x^{p^n}-x$.

Comment: @ponchan, See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907353/irreducible-polynomial-in-mathbbf-px-divides-xpn-x/3907430#3907430) answer

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi$ be a root of $f$ in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. $\{1, \xi, \dots, \xi^{n-1}\}$ is a linearly independent family over $\mathbb F_p$. Therefore $f$ is the minimal polynomial $\mu_{\mathbb F_p, \xi}$ of $\xi$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

And as $\xi$ is a root of $q(x)=x^{p^n}-x$, $f$ divides $q$ which splits in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. Consider the long division of $q$ by $f$ to be convinced by this statement.

Comment: What is $P$ supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry... I renamed $f$ into $P$. Answer updated.

Comment: Why is $\xi$ a root of $q(x)$?

Comment: Because $q$ vanishes for all elements of $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ and that $\xi$ is a root of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

By construction, $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ containing a root $a$ of $f$. Since $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, and every element of the latter field is a root of $x^{p^n}-x$, it follows that $f$ and $x^{p^n}-x$ both have $a$ as a root. But since $f$ is irreducible, we must have that $f|x^{p^n}-x$ and so all the roots of $x$ are roots of $x^{p^n}-x$, which in turn implies that all the roots of $f$ are in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and so $f$ splits there.